# UWP WrapPanel Replacement?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is there a replacement for this WPF code?

```
<WrapPanel>
    <TextBlock Width="100" Height="20"/>
    <TextBlock Width="30" Height="50"/>
    <TextBlock Width="150" Height="70"/>                    
</WrapPanel>
```

This is really stupid if there is none...

**Update:**

I forgot to mention that the width of the WrapPanel is smaller than the total width of all the TextBlocks combined.  This means that some of the items need to wrap to a second row.

I thought that this is what most people used a WrapPanel for, but apparently some use it for a Horizontal StackPanel (In this case, you should set the StackPanel's `Orientation` to `Horizontal`...)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well well, 5 minutes after I posted this I found the VariableSizedWrapGrid!  Its the exact replacement, just a different name (?!?).

Comment: Yeah, but it allows you to have items that vary in size - hence the name. You can use ColSpan and RowSpan to achieve that.

Comment: They're not the same.  See [here](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit) and search the page for "WrapPanel".

Comment: This answer is wrong, testing with your code example yields an immediate effect that is similar to vertically oriented items in a StackPanel while a WrapPanel in a WPF application would immediately yield horizontally arranged items.

Answer (score 10):

Another alternative:

1. Install the Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls library package from NuGet
2. Use the WrapPanel Control

Easy.